# How to call a monotonic function that takes a value?

Tags: functions

I'm looking for a name for a family of functions that are characterized by:

- $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$
- $f$ monotonic
- $\exists x \in \mathbb{N} \;.\; f(x) = 0$

(Assuming $0 \in \mathbb{N}.$)

Comment: @Clayton that looks like a comprehensive answer to me.

Comment: Right @Clayton, do you want to post this as answer?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: Posted as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @thpani: Posted as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're assuming $0\in\Bbb N$, if $f$ is increasing, most people would just say $f(0)=0$ or if it is decreasing, $f$ is eventually zero.

**Edit:** Before the question edit, it wasn't explicitly stated that $0\in\Bbb N$. In this case, if you AREN'T assuming $0\in \Bbb N$, it's called the empty set.